# Static cast of enum to bool, performance warning from Compiler

Tags: c++, casting, enums, warnings, static-cast

I have the following declared in my project:

```
enum class OType : bool { Dynamic=true, Static=false };
OType getotype();
```

I'm using the following function:

```
double ComputeO(double K,bool type)
```

I'm calling it this way :

`ComputeO(some double, static_cast<bool>(getotype()))`

For this static_cast I'm getting a nice:

```
warning C4800: 'const dmodel::OType ' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
```

I don't know how to get rid of it,I specify the cast explicitly shouldnt it be enough ?

Note: I'm using VC11 ( Visual Studio 2012 )

Thks.

Comment: Why don't you just take `OType` instead of `bool` in `ComputeO`? That would prevent confusing code like `ComputeO(some double, false); // what does false mean?`.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can't change ComputeO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy.aspx, which describes the warning. In particular, it says:

> Casting the expression to type bool will not disable the warning,
>   which is by design.

Just rewrite your call like this:

```
enum class OType : bool { Dynamic=true, Static=false };
OType getotype();
double ComputeO(double K,bool type);

int main()
{
    ComputeO(1.0, getotype() == OType::Dynamic);
}
```